# what to use to top off blueberry wine?

Tags: wine, fruit, aging

What should I use to top off my carboy of blueberry wine?  I don't want to add water if I can help it.  Adding more juice will just start fermenting again.  Any suggestions on an acceptable wine to add?

Comment: How *much* of this other liquid do you need to add? What's wrong with water, as long as it's clean and sterilized? I think if you add wine, it will not be a "pure" blueberry wine (unless you top it off with blueberry wine from another batch), but that may not matter much...?

Comment: I'm guessing about a quart or so.  I racked the wine so I have a bit less than before.  I was afraid water would just, well, water it down.

Comment: What proportion of the total volume would be added water?

Comment: It's a 6 gal carboy, so that would be 23 qt of wine plus 1 qt of added water.

Comment: 1/24 = ~4.2% ... so about 4% of the total volume would be added water. I'm actually not sure if that's enough to be noticeably watered down.

Comment: I see.  This is my first batch, so I wasn't sure how much of a difference it would make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a suitable wine, and wish to reduce the headspace, use sanitized marbles for displacement.